# How to Post $variable

Tags: php, variables, post

I'm trying to post a variable to another page but when i give a manual value it works. As;

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="productid" value="8" />';
```

and on the second page i can get it with;

```
$p_id = $_POST['productid'];
```

What i want to do is;

instead of manually written value, writing something like;

```
$product_id = $this->product->pr_id;
```

and using the $product_id in value.

I tried many kind of things like

```
value="<?php echo $product_id ; ?>
```

but didn't work. Or what is the right way to send a variable?

Any help will be appriciated.

**EDIT:**

1st Page;

```
<?php 
$product_id = $this->product->virtuemart_product_id;
echo $product_id;

echo ' <input type="file" name="files[]" id="upload" size="50" class="inputbox" multiple/><br />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="productid" value="' . $product_id . '" />';
var_dump($product_id);
```

?>

2nd Page;

```
$p_id = $_POST['productid'];
$query2=mysql_query("INSERT into jos_virtuemart_product_medias (`virtuemart_product_id`,`virtuemart_media_id`) VALUES ($p_id,$media_id)  ");
```

this works only if i write a number manually on 1st page to value.

Comment: Is `$product_id` empty? Are you closing `value="<?php echo $product_id ; ?>"`?

Comment: At some point you have to know what you are using therefore have to reference the value manually somewhere at some-point (unless you just loop through array values and print them all out). Are you trying to abstract it into a class object?

Comment: @MichaelRushton - No it is not empty and yes i am closing the tags sorry for missing syntax

Comment: @Danny - The id is sending to 2nd page to be written database. But i can only get it work when i write manually a number like "8" .

Comment: Is your form `method="POST"`?

Comment: @Danny - Yes its method is Post

Comment: Show us the whole form. It should work based on what you've said.

Comment: Your edit does not contain the whole form. The `<form` tag is missing.

Comment: @Sven - Yes it does not because it is a part of virtuemart joomla and the tags are in totally different places. On the other hand i am asking this just to learn; if it can be sent by manually given value, what is the important part of the starting tag in this situation?

Comment: You should always be able to have a look at the generated html source code and copy it from there. If the source is wrong because of any module incompatibility, there would be nothing you can do but to repair this completely unrelated problem.

Comment: @Sven - Thanks for the view of angle.According to that i checked the rendered part and i saw virtuemart adds its own code to "name" and "value" but when i add the same things nothing happens. It's strange. I think i have to check how its "Save Function" works. But why manually written number can be posted and a "variable" can't whic also can be seen it is set..

Answer (score 2):

If `$product_id` is actually set, this should work:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="productid" value="' . $product_id . '" />';
```

or alternatively:

```
<input type="hidden" name="productid" value="<?php echo $product_id ; ?>" />
```

Comment: tnx for answering i also tried this too but didn't work for me.

Comment: Try `var_dump($product_id);` and verify, that you're variable is really setted.

Comment: @dene - when i try it i get = string(1) "6"

Comment: View the HTML that is being generated, it should be: `<input type="hidden" name="productid" value="6" />`.

Comment: @nickb - Yes i can see that on HTML view

Comment: Then it must behave exactly the same then if you put it manually in your php-code ... can you provide a link? Alternatively, you can check with the Firefox-Extension "HTTPFox", which values are submitted with GET/POST.

Comment: @dene - yes it must but it doesn't which is driving me crazy for 2 days

Comment: @dene- sorry i now saw the rest of your comment. I am gonna check now i don't know hot to do but i will figure out

Comment: Could you provide us two working example links? First one, which is working ("manually") and the second one with the "dynamic" product_id?

Comment: @dene - it's on localhost and part of virtuemart joomla.

Comment: ... or just post us both source codes from the rendered HTML?  :)